# Where to put native code for Phonegap 3.0 plugin?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I just upgraded one of my projects to PhoneGap 3.0 and was wondering the proper methodology for developing a custom plugin. I'm following the Echo plugin example from the developer docs. Should the Echo.h and Echo.m files go in the Plugins folder in the project root, or within the Plugins folder for the specific platform being built?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Cordova first plugin - plugin.xml to inject a feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135526/ios-cordova-first-plugin-plugin-xml-to-inject-a-feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Echo Plugin for iOS and it's working for me. I put Echo.h and Echo.m under platforms/ios/TestProject/Plugins/.  Root folder plugins keep plugins your download from command line. It will be auto installed when you make iOS, Android or other platforms.